# Optimization of Holt-Winter's smoothing parameters using optim() stops after zero iterations [R]

Tags: r, optimization, forecasting

For a high number of time series, I want to optimize the smoothing parameters of the Holt-Winter's forecasting method so that I get one set of optimal parameters. There are three parameters: `alpha`, `beta`, and `gamma`. Below I present a simplified procedure for one time series to indicate the problems encountered. I create a seasonal time series as follows:

```
check_vec <- rep(c(7,6,5,4,3,2,1), times = 100)
check_ts <- ts(check_vec, frequency = 7)
```

The time series looks like the following.

```
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(100, 7) 
Frequency = 7 
  [1] 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6
 [52] 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4
[103] 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2
[154] 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7
[205] 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5
[256] 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3
[307] 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
[358] 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6
[409] 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4
[460] 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2
[511] 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7
[562] 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5
[613] 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3
[664] 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Then, I use the following function to use for optimization:

```
check_func <- function(param) {
  
  a <- param[[1]]
  b <- param[[2]]
  c <- param[[3]]
  
  if (c > 1 - a | a < b) {
    
    return(100000)
    
  } else {
    
    rmse <- accuracy(hw(check_ts, h = 14, alpha = a, beta = b, gamma = c))[2]
    
    return(rmse)
    
  }
  
}
```

The function thus returns the root mean squared error (which I want to minimize). It returns different values for different inputs.

```
> check_func(c(a = 0.18, b = 0.07, c = 0.1))
[1] 3.77942e-16
> check_func(c(a = 0.18, b = 0.07, c = 0.2))
[1] 3.382083e-16
```

I use the following `optim()` command to optimize the parameters:

```
optim(par = c(a = 0.18, b = 0.07, c = 0.1),
      fn = check_func,
      lower = c(0.005,0.005,0.005),
      upper = c(0.99, 0.99, 0.99),
      method = "L-BFGS-B",
      control = list(trace = 6,
                     pgtol = 1.490117e-08))
```

Executing the `optim()` command gives the initial parameters as result (that is zero iterations of the optimization procedure. It returns the following message.

```
N = 3, M = 5 machine precision = 2.22045e-16
L = 0.005 0.005 0.005 
X0 = 0.18 0.07 0.1 
U = 0.99 0.99 0.99 
At X0, 0 variables are exactly at the bounds
At iterate     0  f=       37.794  |proj g|=            0

iterations 0
function evaluations 1
segments explored during Cauchy searches 0
BFGS updates skipped 0
active bounds at final generalized Cauchy point 0
norm of the final projected gradient 0
final function value 37.7942

X = 0.18 0.07 0.1 
F = 37.7942
final  value 37.794202 
converged
$par
   a    b    c 
0.18 0.07 0.10 

$value
[1] 37.7942

$counts
function gradient 
       1        1 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

I have tried to increase the scale of the output of the function and decrease `pgtol` without any success. Does somebody know what to do?

**EDIT** I have added more code and results of the procedure I found.

**EDIT 2** This is the modified `check_func` I use to test whether the method of Enrico works.

```
check_func <- function(param) {
  
  a <- param[[1]]
  b <- param[[2]]
  c <- param[[3]]
  
  rmse <- try(accuracy(hw(check_ts, h = 14, alpha = a, beta = b, gamma = c))[2])
  if (inherits(rmse, "try-error"))
    return(200)
  else
    return(rmse)
  
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might get more-helpful answers if you provided a reproducible example. Are `accuracy` and `hw` from package `forecast`?  In any case, you could try a grid search:

```
library("NMOF")
res <- gridSearch(check_func,
                  lower = rep(0.05, 3),
                  upper = rep(0.99, 3),
                  n = 10)
## List of 4
##  $ minfun   : num 4.11e-17
##  $ minlevels: num [1:3] 0.05 0.05 0.886
##  $ values   : num [1:1000] 3.81e-16 3.81e-16 ...
##  $ levels   :List of 1000
##   ..$ : num [1:3] 0.05 0.05 0.05
##   ..$ : num [1:3] 0.154 0.05 0.05
##   ..$ : num [1:3] 0.259 0.05 0.05
```

For many parameter choices, `check_func` would fail. So I'd safeguard the computation with something like:

```
rmse <- try(accuracy(hw(check_ts, h = 14, alpha = a, beta = b, gamma = c))[2])
  if (inherits(rmse, "try-error"))
      return(200)
```

(Disclosure: I am the maintainer of package [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF).)

Comment: Thank you for your help! `accuracy` and `hw` are indeed from the `forecast` package. I have tried to incorporate the modified `rmse` function to execute the optimisation through the following modified version of `check_func` (I have included it in the edited version of my question). However, this still yields 0 iterations. Am I misssing something?